# Trying to create a trigger for a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a table `[dbo].[main]` composed of 4 columns:

- MovieGenre
- MusicGenre
- PodcastGenre
- CombinedColumn

I want to create a trigger where if anything is inserted in `MovieGenre`, `PodcastGenre`, `MusicGenre` that it also gets inserted into `CombinedColumn`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [dbo].[Main]
FOR INSERT
AS
???
GO
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: The syntax is not mysql.

Comment: I apologize I wanted sql server.

Comment: **How** should this be "combined"? You most likely only need a **computed column** - no trigger at all ..

Comment: This sounds like something that would be much better dealt with at the *presentation* layer rather than *data* that needs to be stored in the database. Is there any reason that this 4th column shouldn't just be generated in the appropriate screens/reports?

Answer (score 0):

--dbo.main` needs a key column (let's say its a identity column 'id1')
     CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert 
        ON [dbo].[Main] 
        FOR INSERT AS 
             declare @allcols varchar(500)

```
         declare @key1 int

         set @key1 = ident_current('dbo.main')

         select  @allcols = MovieGenre+' '+ PodcastGenre+' '+ MusicGenre from inserted

 update dbo.main set CombindedColumn= @allcols where id1  = @key1
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for your response. 
I do not want the combined column to be a concatination of the other 3 columns for example:

Combined column should be 
"stacking" the values: 

so it would be:
Combinedcolumn:
Movie1
Pod1 
Music1 

instead of:

Movie1+Pod1+Music1

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this will add values to Combined Column one after another. "Stacking" them as you want:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert on dbo.main
AFTER INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO yourTable(CombinedColumn)
    SELECT MovieGenre
    FROM inserted
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PodcastGenre
    FROM inserted
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MusicGenre
    FROM inserted
GO
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for your response. 
I do not want the combined column to be a concatination of the other 3 columns for example:

Combined column should be 
"stacking" the values: 

so it would be:
Combinedcolumn:
Movie1
Pod1 
Music1 

instead of:

Movie1+Pod1+Music1

Comment: Ah, I see. What table is CombinedColumn in?

Comment: marc_s is right (my trigger is unnecessary) - use a computed column. You only need a trigger if you are updating another table.

Comment: a calcualted column won't insert a value one after another.

Comment: Yeah, try my trigger out. It should do what you want.